# Does PyQt5 support Qt3D?

Tags: pyqt5, qt3d

I'm pretty new with PyQt, but I just upgraded to the version 5 expecting that I could use the Qt3D (that is available with Qt5), but when I've tried to import the module it always says "Unresolved reference to Qt3d". So I've searched in the PyQt documentation and there is no reference of the Qt3D module, because of that I want to know:

- is it possible to use Qt3D with PyQt5?

  - if so, how can I do it?
  - if not, wich other libraries can I use to make a 3D visualization of a 3D model imported another program like Blender.

(I tought about vPython, but I couldn't figure it out how to import from another file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
As ekhumoro pointed out, there is in fact support for it. See
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt3d/intro

Doesn't seem to be the case, at least not yet.

> > On 23 Mar 2016, at 11:47 pm, Miguel Alejandro Fernandez  wrote:
> >
> > in the next version 5.6 include support for 3D libraries?
>
> It won't be in PyQt v5.6. It might be in PyQt v5.6.1 if the documentation has improved.
>
> Phil

From https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-March/037147.html

You could try using [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/)

Comment: That's old news - [PyQt3D](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt3d/intro) is already available.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, I updated my answer. Weird that I missed this... Do you know why it is not in the standard PyQt package?

Comment: I'm not sure. It consists of five modules, so maybe it would be too big to bundle with the main PyQt5 distribution. Most users/developers will never need it.